# URL check with Prometheus by giving username/password

Tags: url, prometheus

I am looking a way to see if Prometheus can do checks on any URL is working or not by logging into that particular application automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is using the [Blackbox exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter). It allows probing of endpoints over HTTP, HTTPS, DNS, TCP, and ICMP.